# Stash corrupting data in EE3

Tags: stash, ee3

Have simple use of stash in a template.  Worked fine in EE2, but with EE3 after upgrade stash is scrambling the content.

Here is an example of the kind of issue.  Example short-hand stash-set / stash-get syntax (but using long hand doesn't fix)

Value stored via this type of tag:

```
{exp:stash:value parse="yes"}test{/exp:stash:value}
```

And retrieved via this kind of tag:

```
{exp:stash:value process="end"}
```

In EE2 the second tag faithfully provides the required value (i.e. 'test').  In EE3 (for the test string 'test') I'm seeing this:

```
{cf517f46e6ed2e6b3d3f7e67d457f36f1602617362}
```

Any ideas how I can fix this?

Comment: EE2 and EE3 third party add-ons (expect for plugins mostly) are not compatible. Is there an EE3 version of Stash (or has it been explicitly stated it's current state is compatible with EE3)?

Comment: Yep - this is the EE3 version of Stash (3.0.3 from Devot.ee) - but for good measure I've also tried the version available from the croxton git page (3.0.4) - which is showing up as installed OK in the EE3 Add-on panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ExpressionEngine (**all** versions) will choke if you use the same tag as a single *and* as a pair in the same template:

```
{exp:stash:test process="end"}

{exp:stash:test}Test value{/exp:stash:test}
```

It could be that this worked for you in EE2 but not in EE3 because of subtle changes to the parser, but it would have been a fluke that it seemed to work at all.

This will work:

```
{exp:stash:get name="test" process="end"}

{exp:stash:test}Test value{/exp:stash:test}
```

Or:

```
{exp:stash:test process="end"}

{exp:stash:set name="test"}Test value{/exp:stash:set}
```

Or:

```
{exp:stash:get name="test" process="end"}

{exp:stash:set name="test"}Test value{/exp:stash:set}
```

Comment: OK - helpful I guess.  Does this mean that the entry in Stash/Wiki is wrong and / or needs revision?  The entry on this page https://github.com/croxton/Stash/wiki/Short-tag-syntax suggests that the format I was using (short syntax tag pair to set, short syntax tag to get) is legitimate.

Comment: Cheers I've updated the wiki to explain this limitation with the short tag syntax.